# SUM by not all fields from GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

I have table :

```
Id(int), 
CompanyId(uniqueidentifier), 
DateCreated(datetime), 
TypeId(int), 
Value(int), 
Date(date)
```

and query:

```
SELECT 
    W2CliendId,
    CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Date), 0) AS date) AS MonthStarts,
    CASE 
      WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN '4 Search views'
      WHEN TypeId = 2 THEN '5 Maps views'
      WHEN TypeId = 0 THEN 'Unknown'
    END AS [Type],
    SUM(Value) AS [Value]
FROM CompanyTypeValues CTV
    JOIN CompanyProfile CP
        ON CP.CompanyId = CTV.CompanyId
WHERE CP.Status = 0 AND Date >= '2015-08-11'
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Date), 0) AS date), TypeId, W2CliendId
ORDER BY TypeId, MonthStarts, W2CliendId
```

How can I `SELECT` sum by only 2 fields from `GROUP BY`? (`DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Date), 0), W2CliendId`)

Comment: Do you mean you just want to remove `TypeId` from your `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat, well "remove" only for SUM... I need total value for `MonthStarts, W2CliendId`

Comment: Oh. Then maybe you should use a subquery.

Comment: Do you mean that TypeID is not relevant to the totals? In which case, I think you need to leave TypeID out altogether. If you want subtotals per ClientID/MonthStart/TypeID, and also a total per ClientID/MonthStart, then you would need two queries with two result sets. You could generate a temp table with the subtotals, then query that temp table to get the totals.

Comment: I guess, simple window function should do the trick. Or is there something more complicated?

Comment: If you remove TypeId from group, there will be many TypeId values inside the resulting group. Which one do you want to display? First? Last? 0? 1? 2?

Comment: could you give some example data ?
I can not understand what you mean by your question

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 3 type Ids (seems that it is the case from your CASE above the sum) a solution can be to create three columns which repeat the case so that you have 3 aggregate results corresponding to the three type Ids:

So at the end of your query, replace the

```
SUM(Value) AS [Value]
```

BY

```
SUM(CASE 
      WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN Value
      WHEN TypeId = 2 THEN 0
      WHEN TypeId = 0 THEN 0
END AS [Value_Type1],
SUM(CASE 
      WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN 0
      WHEN TypeId = 2 THEN Value
      WHEN TypeId = 0 THEN 0
END AS [Value_Type2],
SUM(CASE 
      WHEN TypeId = 1 THEN 0
      WHEN TypeId = 2 THEN 0
      WHEN TypeId = 0 THEN Value
END AS [Value_Type0],
```

Group by is not designed to aggregate at two different levels in the same query. What you can do otherwise is two separate subqueries, one which aggregates on 3 columns and the other one which aggregages on 2 columns, and join the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Window Function if you have to partition by selected columns

```
SELECT   w2cliendid, 
         cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, date), 0) AS date) AS monthstarts, 
         CASE 
                  WHEN typeid = 1 THEN '4 Search views' 
                  WHEN typeid = 2 THEN '5 Maps views' 
                  WHEN typeid = 0 THEN 'Unknown' 
         END                                                                                                                                         AS [Type],
         sum(value) OVER (partion BY cast(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, date), 0) AS date)
         , w2cliendid ORDER BY typeid, monthstarts, w2cliendid) AS [Value] 
FROM     companytypevalues ctv 
JOIN     companyprofile cp 
ON       cp.companyid = ctv.companyid 
WHERE    cp.status = 0 
AND      date >= '2015-08-11'
```